# Wordpress - How to set different posts per page number for two different categories?

Tags: php, wordpress

On my Wordpress website I have two categories: **news** and **club**. How to set number of posts per page to 10 for **news** category and 4 posts per page for **club** category?

I have set number of posts per page in Settings > Reading to 10 and **news** works as I want but not **club**

I have custom loop in club category where I set posts_per_page to 4.
In category-club.php I have

```
$args=array(
    'category_name'=>'club',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'desc',
    'paged' => ((get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1)
  );
```

But there is problem when I switch to page 2 of posts in this category. I get 404 error. I think it's because I have less than 10 posts in this category.

Can anyone tell me what should I do to get second and next pages work?

Comment: You'd have to create 2 queries with specific post per page and categories set.

Comment: in news category I have default loop, and in category-club.php I have loop with args posted above

Comment: But the categories, in wp are always pulled from `index.php` so you'll need to fix it there, not in a separate `.php` file. You could create a page template with a custom query, but then you wouldn't be able to add them as categories in the menu, but pages...

Comment: @dingo_d Unfortunately you are totally wrong here. Running extra queries is definitely the wrong way to go here. Just another point, I do not know where you get your info from about that categories are always pulled from `index.php`. If the correct category template is available, WordPress will use that. `index.php` is only used if no category template or `archive.php`  is available. Also, creating a page will not solve the issue, it will just create even more issues ;-)

Comment: I never seem to get used to fiddling with `pre_get_posts`. Is there a noticeable slowdown if one uses multiple queries? About the `index.php`, I thought that it's the primary template where the main query is executed (it certainly seems so given [this graph](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png) )...

Comment: @dingo_d You should download and install Query Monitor and run some of your own tests. You will see a definite increase in time spend and the amount of queries. You will definitely do yourself a favor in playing around with `pre_get_posts`. The main query runs on each and every front end page load regardless of which page or archive you query. The results from what is being retrieved is displayed by the default loop. It is quite a huge aspect of WordPress that you will need to look into ;-)

Comment: @dingo_d Also, `index.php` is a last resort, fall back template for all pages and archives. It is a must-have template. All other templates are nice-to-have templates that are not necessary for a theme to operate.

Comment: Wow, there is so much I still don't know O.o Thanks for the explanation :) I will definitely look into it. I was planing on playing with vagrant, I'll definitely install query monitor and see the results. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be running custom queries in place of the main query. They always lead to more issues, and pagination is always one of them as you have experienced. Also, running custom queries in place of the main query slows your page down, so it is always a loose-loose situation.

If you need to change something in the main query, use `pre_get_posts` to achieve what you need. You can try the following: (*Just remember to go back to the default loop in your category pages*)

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    if (    !is_admin() // Only target the frontend
         && $q->is_main_query() // Only target the main query
         && is_category() // Only target category pages
    ) {
        if ( is_category( 'news' ) )
            $q->set( 'posts_per_page', 10 );

        if ( is_category( 'club' ) )   
            $q->set( 'posts_per_page', 4 );
    }
});
```